# Backbone.Marionette Layout: Access region.layout.view directly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Marionette application which as more than 1 region.

```
App.addRegions({
    pageRegion: '#page',
    contentsRegion :'#contents'
});
```

As part of App.pageRegion, I add a layout.

```
App.ConfiguratorLayout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '#configurator-page',
     regions: {
       CoreConfiguratorRegion: '#Core-Configurator-Region',
       SomeOtherRegion:'#someOtherregion'
   }
});
```

This layout is rendered before the application starts.

```
App.addInitializer(function() {
 var configLayout = new App.ConfiguratorLayout();
 App.pageRegion.show(configLayout);
});
```

Later on in the application, I just need to change the contents of the configLayout.

I am trying to achieve something like this.
    App.pageRegion.ConfiguratorLayout.CoreConfiguratorRegion.show(someOtherLayout);

Is there a way to do this besides using DOM selector on the $el of App.pageRegion.

App.pageRegion.$el.find('#...')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of in an app initializer, move the `configLayout` initialization code into a controller that can keep a reference to it and then `show()` something in one of its regions.

```
// pseudocode:

ConfigController = Marionette.Controller.extend({

    showConfig: function() {

        var layout = new App.ConfiguratorLayout();
        App.pageRegion.show(configLayout);

        var someOtherLayout = new App.CoreConfiguratorLayout();
        layout.coreConfiguratorRegion.show(someOtherLayout);

        // ... maybe create and show() some views here?

    }

});

App.addInitializer(function() {
    var controller = new ConfigController();

    // more likely this would be bound to a router via appRoutes, instead of calling directly
    controller.showConfig();
});
```

Comment: The layout had to be shared between various modules. I added that as as a submodule variable. That did the trick. Thanks a ton but.